# Method 'Union' of object '_Global' failed on cells that are on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

As far as I can tell, I have everything declared correctly (albeit complicated), I just need a fresh set of eyes.  According to the compiler my "MultiForm1" union is incorrect:

```
Sub ShiftMaster()
'Declarations
Dim Mon As Range, Tue As Range, Wed As Range, Thu As Range, Fri As Range, Sat As Range, Sun As Range, _
 Multi1 As Range, Multi2 As Range, Multi3 As Range, Multi4 As Range, Multi5 As Range, Multi6 As Range, _
 DayNum As Range, MonFormOne As Range, MonFormTwo As Range, MonFormThree As Range, TueFormOne As Range, _
 TueFormTwo As Range, TueFormThree As Range, WedFormOne As Range, WedFormTwo As Range, WedFormThree As Range, _
 ThuFormOne As Range, ThuFormTwo As Range, ThuFormThree As Range, FriFormOne As Range, FriFormTwo As Range, _
 FriFormThree As Range, SatFormOne As Range, SatFormTwo As Range, SatFormThree As Range, SunFormOne As Range, _
 SunFormTwo As Range, SunFormThree As Range, ShiftNum As Range, MultiForm1 As Range, MultiForm2 As Range, _
 MultiForm3 As Range, MultiForm4 As Range, MultiForm5 As Range, MultiForm6 As Range, MultiForm7 As Range

Set Mon = Sheets("Production").Range("B3:F26")
Set Tue = Sheets("Production").Range("K3:O26")
Set Wed = Sheets("Production").Range("T3:X26")
Set Thu = Sheets("Production").Range("AC3:AG26")
Set Fri = Sheets("Production").Range("AL3:AP26")
Set Sat = Sheets("Production").Range("AU3:AY26")
Set Sun = Sheets("Production").Range("BD3:BH26")
Set Multi1 = Union(Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun)
Set Multi2 = Union(Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun)
Set Multi3 = Union(Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun)
Set Multi4 = Union(Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun)
Set Multi5 = Union(Fri, Sat, Sun)
Set Multi6 = Union(Sat, Sun)
Set DayNum = Sheets("Command Console").Range("J22")
Set MonFormOne = Sheets("Production").Range("H9")
Set MonFormTwo = Sheets("Production").Range("H17")
Set MonFormThree = Sheets("Production").Range("H25")
Set TueFormOne = Sheets("Production").Range("H33")
Set TueFormTwo = Sheets("Production").Range("H41")
Set TueFormThree = Sheets("Production").Range("H49")
Set WedFormOne = Sheets("Production").Range("H57")
Set WedFormTwo = Sheets("Production").Range("H65")
Set WedFormThree = Sheets("Production").Range("H73")
Set ThuFormOne = Sheets("Production").Range("H81")
Set ThuFormTwo = Sheets("Production").Range("H89")
Set ThuFormThree = Sheets("Production").Range("H97")
Set FriFormOne = Sheets("Production").Range("H105")
Set FriFormTwo = Sheets("Production").Range("H113")
Set FriFormThree = Sheets("Production").Range("H121")
Set SatFormOne = Sheets("Production").Range("H129")
Set SatFormTwo = Sheets("Production").Range("H137")
Set SatFormThree = Sheets("Production").Range("H145")
Set SunFormOne = Sheets("Production").Range("H153")
Set SunFormTwo = Sheets("Production").Range("H161")
Set SunFormThree = Sheets("Production").Range("H169")
Set ShiftNum = Sheets("Command Console").Range("J24")
**Set MultiForm1 = Union(MonFormOne, MonFormTwo, MonFormThree, TueFormOne, TueFormTwo, TwoFormThree, WedFormOne, WedFormTwo, WedFormThree, _
 ThuFormOne, ThuFormTwo, ThuFormThree, FriFormOne, FriFormTwo, FriFormThree, SatFormOne, SatFormTwo, SatFormThree, SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)**
Set MultiForm2 = Union(TueFormOne, TueFormTwo, TwoFormThree, WedFormOne, WedFormTwo, WedFormThree, ThuFormOne, ThuFormTwo, ThuFormThree, _
 FriFormOne, FriFormTwo, FriFormThree, SatFormOne, SatFormTwo, SatFormThree, SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)
Set MultiForm3 = Union(WedFormOne, WedFormTwo, WedFormThree, ThuFormOne, ThuFormTwo, ThuFormThree, FriFormOne, FriFormTwo, FriFormThree, _
 SatFormOne, SatFormTwo, SatFormThree, SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)
Set MultiForm4 = Union(ThuFormOne, ThuFormTwo, ThuFormThree, FriFormOne, FriFormTwo, FriFormThree, SatFormOne, SatFormTwo, SatFormThree, _
 SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)
Set MultiForm5 = Union(FriFormOne, FriFormTwo, FriFormThree, SatFormOne, SatFormTwo, SatFormThree, SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)
Set MultiForm6 = Union(SatFormOne, SatFormTwo, SatFormThree, SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)
Set MultiForm7 = Union(SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)

'###########################################################################################################
'#                              Selects cells for format deletion, calls deleter                           #
'###########################################################################################################

Sheets("Production").Select
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
If DayNum = 1 Then
Multi1.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 2 Then
Multi2.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 3 Then
Multi3.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 4 Then
Multi4.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 5 Then
Multi5.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 6 Then
Multi6.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 7 Then
Sun.Select
Else
MsgBox ("There is a problem with the day number formula")
End If
Call BorderBlaster

'###########################################################################################################
'#                                          End Format deletion                                            #
'###########################################################################################################

'###########################################################################################################
'#                            Chooses latent formulas for deletion, calls deleter                          #
'###########################################################################################################

If DayNum = 1 Then
MultiForm1.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 2 Then
MultiForm2.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 3 Then
MultiForm3.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 4 Then
MultiForm4.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 5 Then
MultiForm5.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 6 Then
MultiForm6.Select
ElseIf DayNum = 7 Then
MultiForm7.Select
Else
MsgBox ("There is a problem with the day number formula")
End If

Call FormulaBlaster

'###########################################################################################################
'#                                          End Formula Deletion                                           #
'###########################################################################################################

Call BorderDamon

Call FormulaDamon

Call LastRights

End Sub
Sub BorderBlaster()
'Clears borders
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .ThemeColor = 5
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .ThemeColor = 9
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .ThemeColor = 9
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .ThemeColor = 9
        .TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262
        .Weight = xlThick
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
Sub FormulaBlaster()
'Clears formulas
Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
Sub BorderDamon()
'Some Code
End Sub
Sub FormulaDamon()
'Some Code
End Sub
Sub LastRights()
'Some Code
End Sub
```

Obviously the code is incomplete.  Does anyone have any ideas why this would be causing this?

Comment: That is way too much code for someone here to want to read, if you haven't error checked it yourself. Further, I recommend you look into (A) declaring your ranges in Excel as Named Ranges, or (B) creating Arrays of ranges to hold individual declared cells.

Comment: Have you declared `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your code?

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld: No I haven't

Comment: To all: I figured it out.  There is a character limit on union.  I was two characters over.  The entire statement must be 255 or less, I changed my "one"-"two"-and-"three"'s to 1-2-3s.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: See my answer.  You really should be doing this all the time.

Comment: Even when Notepad++ wasn't highlighlighting it, I had a hard time recognizing TwoFormThree instead of TueFormThree.

Comment: @Jeeped  I merely copied his code into the VBE, using a module that had Option Explicit  (as is my practice) and then tried to run it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - So did I. It pointed to the same thing but my old mind and eyes couldn't see the difference at first.

Comment: @DtheHut In Excel 2007, your **corrected** (correcting the variable name) `Set` statement works fine with 271 characters.  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, that sometimes happens to me, too.

Comment: Regardless seems to work now.  I will use option explicit in the future, not something I normally do.

Comment: @DtheHut  Well, if you haven't corrected the undeclared variables that you are using, you may run into some other problems.  For example, if you changed `TwoFormThree` to `2Form3` or some other undeclared variable, it will be a Variant/Object/Range data type which will probably be less efficient than if it were a Range data type.

Comment: I did have that problem originally.  I went through and cleaned them out.  I used find and replace and realized that I actually typed some of them out wrong and replaced with the "tue" where appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go into Tools/Options and select the option to Require Variable Declaration.  This will place `Option Explicit` at the start of any new module you insert.

Had you done this, you would have quickly found your error, as well as the similar errors in other of your Set statements.

```
Set MultiForm1 = Union(MonFormOne, MonFormTwo, MonFormThree, TueFormOne, TueFormTwo, **TwoFormThree**, WedFormOne, WedFormTwo, WedFormThree, _
 ThuFormOne, ThuFormTwo, ThuFormThree, FriFormOne, FriFormTwo, FriFormThree, SatFormOne, SatFormTwo, SatFormThree, SunFormOne, SunFormTwo, SunFormThree)
```

Answer (score 0):

OT: In an effort to clean up some of your code to be a little more reafable, you might consider looping through a [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) collecting the cells on each iteration of the loop. A bulk value (or range) assignment would be preferable if the cells were contiguous but the stagger with Union requires a loop.

Here are two examples for paring down all the code and variables that are currently required to construct and assign the `MultiForm1` variable.

```
Option Explicit

Dim MultiForm1 as Range

'Option1: do it in groups of three on a 24 row stagger
With Worksheets("Production")
    With .Range("H9")
        Set MultiForm1 = .Cells(1)  '<~~ seed MultiForm1
        For h = 0 To 144 Step 24
            Set MultiForm1 = Union(MultiForm1, .Offset(h, 0), .Offset(h + 8, 0), .Offset(h + 16, 0))
        Next h
    End With
End With
Debug.Print MultiForm1.Address(0, 0, external:=True)

'Option2: just cycle through on the 8 row stagger
With Worksheets("Production")
    With .Range("H9")
        Set MultiForm1 = .Cells(1)  '<~~ seed MultiForm1
        For h = 0 To 162 Step 8
            Set MultiForm1 = Union(MultiForm1, .Offset(h, 0))
        Next h
    End With
End With
Debug.Print MultiForm1.Address(0, 0, external:=True)
```

It's always a good idea to keep an eye out for patterns that can be exploited. You probably aren't getting paid by the line for your code.

Less typing == less typos.