# Applying the same Macro to All Worksheets

Tags: vba, for-loop, worksheet

I am trying to run a macro through all worksheets in an Excel workbook. I have the code below, but I am getting a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Union' of object'_Global" failed.

I have looked up the error and tried to "go into Tools/Options and select the option to Require Variable Declaration" from the suggestion below, but it didn't work.

[Method 'Union' of object '_Global' failed on cells that are on the same sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147200/method-union-of-object-global-failed-on-cells-that-are-on-the-same-sheet)

Below is my VBA code that will loop through the entire worksheets.

```
    Sub Bagasse_YG_Update()

    Dim rng As Range, column As Long, row As Long
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
    ' workbook.
    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ' Begin the loop.
    For I = 1 To WS_Count

    'do whatever you need'
    Sheets(I).Select ' Added this command to loop through the sheets

    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Union(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.Resize(1).Offset   (-1).EntireRow).Copy
    ActiveCell.Resize(1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For column = 4 To 43
        If (column + 1) Mod 4 > 0 Then
            For row = 1 To 2
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = ActiveCell.Offset(row, column)
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveCell.Offset(row, column))
                End If
                Next row
            End If
            Next column
            rng.ClearContents

    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-6).EntireRow.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(-5).Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False



    Dim row2 As Long, column2 As Long
    row2 = -2
    For column2 = 5 To 25 Step 4
        ActiveCell.Offset(row2, column2).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(row2 + 1, column2)
        Next column2

    Next I
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If it is possible, this post might benefit from a more detailed runtime error. Is there an associated line that caused the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to reset `rng` to `Nothing` before starting moving to the next sheet:

```
...
Next column
rng.ClearContents

Set rng = Nothing
...
```

To expand off my comments:

When you got to Sheet2, your first iteration of this loop

```
If rng Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = ActiveCell.Offset(row, column)
Else
    Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveCell.Offset(row, column))
End If
```

Is going to go right to `Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveCell.Offset(row, column))` because `rng` wasn't reset to `Nothing`. Then it attempts a `Union` across two worksheets which you can't do.

Comment: Solution verified! It worked after I add `set rng = Nothing` after `rng.ClearContents`. 

Could you elaborate a bit about the solution and the problem that I had? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem is that on your next iteration, `rng` was set to something on Sheet1 - When it saw that `rng` was not set to `Nothing` it attempted to do a `Union` of a range on Sheet1 with a range on Sheet2 - which you can't do, throwing an error :)